# On Google Cloud Storage, does overwriting or deleting an object impact clients actively reading the same object?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Example scenario:

1. I upload a large object `cool_video.mp4` to a GCS bucket.
2. A client requests `cool_video.mp4` and starts downloading the file.
3. The client's connection is slow and the file is large so it will take the client approximately 10 minutes to download the complete file.
4. I then delete (or overwrite) `cool_video.mp4` while the client is halfway through downloading the file.

Will the client's download be interrupted or stopped short? Are they guaranteed to get the complete, original version of the file or would it be possible for them to get a truncated or corrupted file?

Lastly, would it make any difference if versioning was enabled on the GCS bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If versioning is enabled, and you've overwritten the object being read but have not explicitly deleted it, the read will complete just fine. The download will also be resumable, assuming the caller specifies the object generation.

If versioning is not enabled, I do not believe the behavior of how long the download would continue to work has been publicly, explicitly defined.

More importantly, though, is that the download would not be resumable, that is to say, if the TCP connection were lost 9 minutes into the download, resuming that download would fail. Since you cannot put a lot of trust in TCP connections over the Internet to stay up, it would generally not be a good idea to delete an object while you suspect users are still relying on its continued existence, even if GCS guaranteed that such downloads would continue perpetually.